# ayuda para poder ejecutar una pequeña quiniela con php y sql

Tags: php, mysqli

aquí solicitando ayuda para poder ejecutar una pequeña quiniela, tengo el siguiente código que me suma los goles, pero ahora necesito identificar el equipo ganador, compararlo con los datos que ingresa el usuario, puntos por diferencia de goles, puntos si le atino al marcador
Las condiciones son

1. Puntos por marcador
2. Puntos por empate
3. Puntos por el Ganador

```
tabla quiniela
id
quiniela1a
quiniela1b


tabla partido
id
partido1a
partido1b
```

```
Quiniela se compara con Partido, así
quiniela1a (signos menor, igual, mayor) partido1a
quiniela1b (signos menor, igual, mayor) partido1b
```

```
if($data['quiniela1a'] signo menor $data2['partido1a']){
   $intTotalP += 0;
} else if ($data['quiniela1a'] === $data2['partido1a']){
   $intTotalP += 10;
} else if($data['quiniela1a'] > $data2['partido1a']){
   $intTotalP += 10;
}
```

```
if($data['quiniela1b'] signo menor $data2['partido1b']){
   $intTotalP += 0;
} else if ($data['quiniela1b'] === $data2['partido1b']){
   $intTotalP += 10;
} else if($data['quiniela1b'] > $data2['partido1b']){
   $intTotalP += 10;
}
```

Esto equivale a puntos por marcador, esperando este bien la integracion, que si me da el resultado, lo que no logro y ya he intentado de muchas forma pero me da error, motivo por el cual acudo a ustedes para una orientacion o me ayuden con el codigo para poder identificar al GANADOR que tendria puntos y si le atino al marcador tendria otros puntos y si fue empate sus puntos correspondientes.

Aqui donde estoy perdido, perdon pero si me ha costado ubicar esta parte.

```
for (
$arrayGanador = array($data2['partido1a'] signo menor $data2['partido1b']) => 0;
$arrayGanador = array($data2['partido1a'] === $data2['partido1b']) => 10;
$arrayGanador = array($data2['partido1a'] > $data2['partido1b']) => 10
) { 
    $arrayGanador +=
    if($data['quiniela1a'] signo menor $data2['partido1a']){
       $intTotalP += 0;
    } else if ($data['quiniela1a'] === $data2['partido1a']){
       $intTotalP += 10;
    } else if($data['quiniela1a'] > $data2['partido1a']){
       $intTotalP += 10;
    } 
    if($data['quiniela1b'] signo menor $data2['partido1b']){
       $intTotalP += 0;
    } else if ($data['quiniela1b'] === $data2['partido1b']){
       $intTotalP += 10;
    } else if($data['quiniela1b'] > $data2['partido1b']){
       $intTotalP += 10;
    }
}
```

Agradesco la ayuda, exitos a todos.

[image: subo imagen, para poder darme a explicar mejor]

Comment: Hola, el código se ve muy confuso, como cuando pones `signo menor` imagino que querías decir "<", también ¿por que utilizas el operador "==="?, existe diferencia entre este y "==", también el `for` se usa de forma extraña, y por ultimo no entiendo la linea `$arrayGanador +=` ¿por que esta allí? Luego de eso no se ve complicado, si me ayudas con esa información podría darte una respuesta.

Comment: El código que has puesto no parece PHP aunque pones la etiqueta PHP. Incluye solo el código suficiente para permitir a otros reproducir el problema. Para ayuda en esto, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias por responder, no logre colocar todo el código, por alguna razón que aun no conozco no me aparecen los signo, como el menor <, si es codigo php, en donde estan los primeros if estos me dan el resultado, solo que ahora debo identificar al ganador que tendra un punteo y si es empate otro punteo, y asi comparar el marcador puesto en la quiniela. Estoy leyendo ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?, para tener una mejor respuesta, gracias nuevamente por sus comentarios.